# Session issue after upgrade to 64 bit

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Recently we have migrated our web application from 32 bit to 64 bit. However, as an apparent result, we are experiencing strange behaviors with the session values, as the session is picking up old values on invoking the *response.redirect* method.

For example:

During the drop-down event change, we set the below value of the session in *page1.aspx*:

```
Session ("type")= "IN".
```

When we redirect to *page2.aspx*, the value of session ("type") is *Nothing*.

Then during the next invocation of this flow - if we try to set the value of session ("type")  as "OUT" in page1.aspx on the drop-down change event and redirect to page2.aspx - the value of session ("type") is "IN".

This is only happening after the web application migrated from 32 bit to 64 bit, as before in 32 bit it was working fine.
And also this issue is only on the production server, but not on the *test* server nor on the *quality* server.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration was incorrectly configured in [IIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) settings for *workerprocessor*, which had a value of 5 when it should have been 1.

Comment: Where is "workerprocessor" located?

Answer (score 0):

I think with your code you are looking for a session object with that name. What you actually need is the item.

Try this:

Page 1:

```
If Session.item(key) IsNot Nothing Then
    Session.item(key) = value
Else
    Session.Add(key, value)
End If
```

Page 2:

You can access now the value with *Session.Item(key)*.

Comment: But the same code is running fine on other servers except production server. And the same peace of code working fine on Google chrome.Also it was working before migration our application to 64bit